# Java Android Studio Generate a document from a template [.docx]

Tags: java, android, plugins, docx, xdocreport

I have a problem with the code that I'm trying to generate a document.

**Objective:** Generate a document following a template from .docx in android

My project:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NEm1.jpg

I am using this with plugin: xdocreport-1.0.4.jar

My template **Test.docx:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/firvA.jpg - Type: MergeField

**My Problem:**

[image]


**Code: GeneradorDocumentosService.java** https://github.com/DomingoMG/TemplateDocxAndroid/blob/master/Main.java

```
public static InputStream loadDocumentAsStream(String filePath) throws IOException
 { 
 URL url = new File(filePath).toURI().toURL();
 InputStream documentAsStream = url.openStream();
 return documentAsStream;
 }
```

**Code: Main.java**: https://github.com/DomingoMG/TemplateDocxAndroid/blob/master/Main.java

```
public static void generateDocument(String rutaPlantilla, String extension, boolean convertirPdf) 
throws IOException, XDocReportException
{
    Map<String, Object> variablesMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    variablesMap.put("name", name);
    variablesMap.put("surname", surname);
    variablesMap.put("date", date);

    // 2) Create fields metadata to manage lazy loop (#forech velocity)
    // for table row.
    FieldsMetadata metadata = new FieldsMetadata();
    metadata.addFieldAsList("listaNumeros.Numero");
    metadata.addFieldAsList("listaNumeros.Cuadrado");
    metadata.addFieldAsList("listaNumeros.Raiz");

    // Mapa con las variables de tipo imagen. Estas variables contienen el path de la imagen
    Map<String, String> imagenesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    imagenesMap.put("header_image_logo", "./Logo.png");

    GeneradorDocumentosService generadorDocumentosService = new GeneradorDocumentosService();
    byte[] mergedOutput = generadorDocumentosService.generarDocumento(rutaPlantilla,
            TemplateEngineKind.Freemarker, variablesMap, imagenesMap, convertirPdf
            , metadata
    );

    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("Faycan_Contract_"+"." +extension);
    os.write(mergedOutput);
    os.flush();
    os.close();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtNombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNombre);
    txtApellidos = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtApellidos);
    txtFecha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtFecha);

    name = txtNombre.getText().toString();
    surname = txtApellidos.getText().toString();
    date = txtFecha.getText().toString();

    btnGenerar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGenerar);
    btnGenerar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            try
            {
                generateDocument("file:///android_asset/test.docx", "docx", false);
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The document could not be generated"+e, 
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You should post relevant code in your post. The exception says `FileNotFound` so I would start by checking why it isn't there.

Comment: I already inserted the code that could be the error